# can't get test to pass on view that takes a POST form with a manytomany field

Tags: python, django

My github files are located here https://github.com/cbaldwin20/project_9/blob/master/menu/tests.py

I cannot get this test to pass (note that 'Menu' already has one object in its database, so I am trying to add another to make it 2. Thanks for any advice.

```
def test_create_new_menu_view(self):
        self.client.post('/menu/new', data={
            'expiration_date': timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=2),
                        'season': 'Spring 2018',
                        'created_date': timezone.now(),
                        'items': ['1']
            })
        self.assertEqual(Menu.objects.count(), 2)
```

on this view

```
def create_new_menu(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MenuForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            menu = form.save()
            return redirect('mysite:menu_detail', pk=menu.pk)

    form = MenuForm()
    return render(request, 'menu/new_menu.html', {'form': form})
```

using this form

```
class MenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    expiration_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())
    items = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        exclude = ('created_date',)
```

and this model that the form uses

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    season = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    items = models.ManyToManyField('Item', related_name='items')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form data submitted via HTTP POST in the test method will make a invalid form. You need to send dates in like format (*i.e.* YYYY-MM-DD) as it will have been passed were the form submitted in a browser.

```
def test_create_new_menu_view(self):

    expiration_date = timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=2)

    self.client.post('/menu/new/', data={
        'expiration_date': expiration_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        'season': 'Spring 2018',
        'created_date': timezone.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        'items': ['1']
    })

    self.assertEqual(Menu.objects.count(), 2)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I did a 'form.is_valid' test right above this test, and it passed so I thought I did it correctly but I guess not. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, the test client doesn't event post the data. It's treated as an invalid request.